# Vowpal Wabbit -- Active Learning, predictions always 0 even with seed data

Tags: machine-learning, python

Using Vowpal Wabbit and its `python` interactor for active learning I've got up to the point of being able to send messages back and forth to the server from the client but I am having problems with seeding.

When I seed the model with the current command:

```
python active_interactor.py --verbose -o labelled.txt --seed data.seed localhost 12345 unlabelled.txt
```

The interactor sends the examples to the server (and I know this because the server updates the models and the debug information is produced) but when it feeds the unlabelled examples and asks for a label as a response, the predictions are always `0`.

My question is: is the model not being seeded? If not, why are the predictions always `0` even though there is a model?

It should be noted that the same data can be successfully used to create a passive model that gives non-`0` predictions, so I do not think the problem is with the training data.

---UPDATE---

Upon looking at the tests, we went ahead and changed the vw server to match the test with two parameters in mind that were left as their defaults beforehand, namely initial_t and l.

vw -f final.model --active_learning --active_mellowness 0.000001 --daemon --port 12345 --initial_t 10 -l 10

Once doing this, predictions are produced.  This also works when -l is it's default.  We will now do a grid search to find out the best possible parameters.  One question though, what is the reason why low values of  initial_t led to no predictions?

Comment: This appears focused on the use of particular software and as such off-topic here. If the core question is really or even partly statistical, please reword your question to make that more evident.

Comment: @NickCox My apologies! Thanks for the migration :).